# Basic AJAX test in WordPress returning 400 error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I've followed a very basic tutorial just to figure out the workings of AJAX calls within WordPress. Here are all the relevant bits of code:

In `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/my_query.js', array('jquery') );

    // in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );
}
```

In `my_query.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    console.log('myquery');

    var data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'whatever': ajax_object.we_value      // We pass php values differently!
    };
    // We can also pass the url value separately from ajaxurl for front end AJAX implementations
    jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
```

and at the bottom of `admin-ajax.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
function my_action() {
    global $wpdb;
    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );
    $whatever += 10;
        echo $whatever;
    wp_die();
}
```

This covers all the points in the tutorial, but what I get when I load an admin page is this 400 error, whereas, I should be getting an alert, right?

[image: 400 error message]

Any ideas would be truly appreciated, I'm at my wit's end.

Thanks.

Comment: Wait, you edited `admin-ajax.php`? You're not supposed to edit any core/admin WordPress file, they will be overwritten as soon as you update WP. Your action callback should be added in your theme's `functions.php` or in a plugin.

Comment: 400 is typically related to a request being incorrectly formatted. Double check that you have everything that you need. Things to think about: CSRF token, data-type, etc.

Comment: If a tutorial recommends editing `admin-ajax.php` I'd suggest trying a different one. As Aioros said, that's not the right way to register AJAX callbacks in WordPress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have added your custom code at the end of `admin-ajax.php`. That is **not** the correct way to do this. In general, you should never edit a core/admin WordPress file, because it will be overwritten when you update WordPress (among other reasons).

Even ignoring that, the reason why it's not working is that `admin-ajax.php` is only executed when actually requested, so your callback will be registered too late. You should add your add_action and the relative callback in your theme's `functions.php` or in a plugin, so that your actions will be registered at due time.

Comment: The documentation didn't specify where my_action went. I foolishly assumed if you're pointing it to a file you need to have something in that file to catch it. got it now thanks